# how do i display data using DataGridView from DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have the data into datatable.(all rows and columns),
i want to display the data from datatable to datagridview.

this is method that return my datatable:

```
 Call objCRS_DataAccesslayer.TAXREPORT(vOperation:="GET UNAPPROVED DATA", vSubOperation:="SELECT UNAPPROVED DATA TC", VOutPut:=dt, objType:="SELECT")
```

where' dt' is my datatable 
so whow it is possible ?

Comment: If you're using a `DataGridView` then say so in the title.  a `GridView` is something else.  It's not hard to use the correct names for things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

assuming your DataGridView is called `DataGridView1`

Comment: and how do i display specific column from datatable to gridview

Comment: Add the column in the winforms designer and set its `DataPropertyName` property to the name of your column you wish to display. Also set the datagridview's `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false.

Comment: I would go through this tutorial on datagridviews. Granted the site is old, and you may have to adjust some code, but its a very good resource. @vivekpadelkar http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_tutorial.htm